# If $gxg^{-1}\in X$, $\forall x\in X$, then $\langle X\rangle$=$\langle X\rangle^G\lhd G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Well in this exercise i don't get more information but what is in the title. I don't understand how this set would even look like $\langle X\rangle$.
I'm gessing $\langle X\rangle=\{ x^n| n\in \mathbb N\text{, }\forall x\in X\}$, but it doesn't look right. :S

Comment: What does $<X>^G$ mean ?

Comment: @Amr $A^G$ means $gAg^{-1}, g\in G$

Comment: $\langle X \rangle$ means the subgroup of $G$ generated by $X$, which is the set of all products of the form $a_1a_2\cdots a_k$ (for some $k \ge 0$) with $a_i \in X$ or $a_i^{-1} \in X$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, and $a_i\in G$?? could it be that $X\notin G$??

Comment: $a_i \in X$ is correct. $X$ is a *subset* of $G$, so $X \not\in G$ does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I've done any group theory but I think this is right...

Consider an element of $\langle X \rangle$, say $x_1x_2x_3...x_n,$ with $x_i \in X,$ or $x_i^{-1} \in X$

$gx_1x_2x_3...x_n g^{-1} = gx_1g^{-1}gx_2g^{-1}gx_3g^{-1}g...g^{-1}gx_n g^{-1}$

And since either $gx_ig^{-1} \in X$ or $(gx_ig^{-1})^{-1} \in X$, it follows that $gx_1x_2x_3...x_n g^{-1} \in \langle X \rangle$

Therefore $\langle X \rangle$ is invariant under conjugation, as desired.